# datastax authorizer exception

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise

I'm getting an exception while trying to grant permissions for a created role.

**Command:**

> GRANT ALL PERMISSIONS on KEYSPACE test_ks to ks_admin;

**Error:**

ServerError: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: GRANT operation is not supported by the DseAuthorizer if it is not enabled

**Actions Performed:**

i have updated the cassandra.yaml file to change the authorizer from default to "com.datastax.bdp.cassandra.auth.CassandraAuthorizer" but got an exception when restarted the dse service.

**Exception from system log:**

An exception was caught and reported. Message: Unable to find authorizer class 'com.datastax.bdp.cassandra.auth.CassandraAuthorizer'
  at com.datastax.bdp.DseModule.configure(Unknown Source)

Could someone please let me know what i'm missing here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the CassandraAuthorizer class from org.apache instead:

```
authorizer: org.apache.cassandra.auth.CassandraAuthorizer
```

Comment: Thank you Aaron. It worked ... I have missed enabling authorization rules in dse.yaml file.

Comment: Looks like this isn't allowed anymore, at least I'm getting this in response: `Message: CassandraAuthorizer is incompatible with the DseAuthenticator`